# regularity of solution of ordinary differential equatin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider problem 
\begin{eqnarray}
\left.
\begin{array}{rcl}
u_t &=& f(u,t),\;t>0,\\
u(0) &=& x
\end{array}
\right\rbrace
\end{eqnarray}
where $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $u$ depends also on $x$, of course. What assumption for $f$ is necessary to conclude that $u_x(x,t)$ exists and is continuous for every $(x,t)$ ? Is there a book where I can find it ?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation for $v=u_x$ is
$$
\dot v(x,t) = f_u(u(x,t),t)\,v(x,t), \quad v(x,0)=1,
$$
so that you only need that the partial derivative of $f$ for $u$ exists and is continuous so that the coefficient function $a(x,t)=f_u(u(x,t),t)$ is continuous in $t$ so that $v$ exists globally where $u$ exists.

Comment: The idea seems to be correct, thank you.